# Embed recent YT video (not a short, video)

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, youtube-channels

I'm kind of new to website coding and stuff, but anyways I have a Youtube embed link = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=channel_id`
and I already know how to use it with iframe, but my problem is that I want to get the most recent video and not a shorts video.

I only tried searching this problem but no results.

Is there a way to like filter it or something?